# Scrolling background example?

Tags: android, surfaceview

As a beginner looking for an good example on scrolling background and handling mutli threads or surface view. I come across Lunar Lander and JetBoy (examples given in android as sample) but they are little bit difficult to understand. is there any good example to begin with ? which can be simpler to understand or any one has explained the JetBoy and lunarlander in easy way ?

Comment: Some people may not know what `Lunar Lander` and `Jet Boy` are. Maybe you could also explain what it is exactly that you don't understand about them.

Comment: @aneal : edited the above question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best example for 2d scrolling background is Replica-Island its an open source. 
Here is the link. This will help you.

http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/source/browse/